# Why Einstein was always opposed to uncertainity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, history, measurement-problem, determinism

Einstein always believed that everything is certain,  and we can calculate everything.

And he always rejected Quantum mechanics due to it's factor of uncertainty. But still Quantum physics was right.

Then why Einstein never accepted the fact of uncertainty?

Is there any valid reason? If you know.

Explain it like a story, so it will be interesting.

Comment: Phrasing of the question aside, I don't think this is primarily opinion-based.  There are real historical reasons why Einstein was skeptical of quantum randomness, and real reasons why this was rejected.  There's a real history of physics question here.

Comment: I agree that there's an interesting question here, but I don't necessarily think it's the right fit for this Stack.  You might try asking it over at [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Einstein was stubborn about this matter, because he had preconceptions about it.  It was also the case that quantum reality wasn't firmly established until late in his career.

The most famous objection he had to the reality of wavefunction collapse was in the [EPR paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox), which showed that if wavefunction collapse was real, then you could have the communication of the collapse of the wavefunction travel superluminally, which potentially could create causality problems in special relativity.

This paradox was resolved when it was later shown that wavefunction collapse of distant, entangled particles does not actually communicate any information, and is more akin to the "superluminal" travel of a laser pointer dot across the surface of the moon when fired from the Earth than it is to an actual superluminal particle.  The EPR paradox, however, was important in a lot of ways, most importantly in the way that it inspired [Bell's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem), which showed that one of the following three statements has to be true:

1. Wavefunction collapse is really random
2. Quantum mechanics is wrong
3. Any quantum hidden variables that predetermine the results of collapse experiments involve non-local information

This is the point at which Einstein's position against the reality of quantum randomness became completely untenable, but Einstein was dead by the time that Bell published his paper.  Until then, he could have held out some (probably irrational) hope that there was some theoretical thing in quantum mechanics that was just not completely understood.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that point $2$ can be replaced by point $2'$:  *Certain very specific predictions of quantum mechanics, which have (now) been confirmed experimentally, are wrong.*  $2'$ is considerably less likely to be true than $2$, which enhances the likelihood of $1$ or $3$.

Comment: I would add 4. superdeterminism,  change 1 by "giving up local realism", and add 5:  "and many other possibilities that we have not thought about yet"

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams, well yes, I was clearly not putthing out an exhaustive list of every true statement.  Gödel would have issues with me even making an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just the uncertainty aspect of quantum mechanics, but also the the fact that in the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics (which was standard at that time), the observer including the measurement apparatus would have to be imagined as some external agent for which the laws of physics do not apply in the same was as the rest of the universe. It's then not all that unreasonable to reject such a theory as a candidate for a fundamental theory of Nature. Einstein e.g. once asked whether one should believe if the Moon exists if we don't look at it.

Today there are still unresolved issues w.r.t. quantum mechanics. The discussion today is no longer about uncertainty per se but about information, e.g. whether it can get lost in certain processes. The idea that information can get lost from the universe at the fundamental level (as opposed to merely becoming inaccessible to us in practice), was very controversial when Hawking proposed that this would happen during black hole evaporation. There are many fundamental physics objections against information loss, and Hawking eventually changed his mind on this issue. But many physicists who stick to some form of a collapse interpretation of quantum mechanics are implicitly invoking information loss.